# where can I find a good ruby excel parser that also had good documentation?

Tags: ruby, excel, documentation

I've spent some time today looking for a pure ruby library that will parse an excel workbook. I could find the parseexcel gem in the repos, but the problem is that I can't find any documentation on it. and the rdoc is pitiful. so, my question is 1) is there good documentation out there for this gem? 2) if not, is there another gem that does the same thing that has good documentation?

thx :)

-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) is a good alternative with [documentation](http://roo.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: do you know how to write to xls and xlsx file using roo? No luck with `set_value` method :(